# disable previously enabled mouse with Vim script

Tags: mouse

I've added this script to my vimrc file

```
command! EnableMouse :call EnableMouseFunction()
function! EnableMouseFunction()
    let command = ":set mouse=a"
    exe command
endfunction
```

So, ... what is the method to unset mouse in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need anything that complex

```
set mouse=a
" and
set mouse=
```

are enough.

You can even define your command to be

```
:command! ToggleMouse exe 'set mouse='.(empty(&mouse)?'a':'')
" Here I use `:exe` because I didn't want to use `:if` in a command definition which would look like:
:command! ToggleMouse if empty(&mouse) | set mouse=a | else | set mouse= | endif
```

Comment: Your ToggleMouse command is unnecessary. The built-in command `:set mouse!` will toggle. See `:help :set-inv`

Comment: @Kevin, it's not possible in that case. `'mouse'` isn't a boolean option.

Comment: Ah I see; apologies.

Comment: @kevin. Don't worry. It was a good remark in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the mouse is controlled (as you find out) with the `mouse` setting. It is activated only if `mouse` is equal to "something". This something determines when is the mouse used.

To disable the mouse you can simply:

```
set mouse=
```

---

Also in your function, you can call the `set` command directly:

```
function! EnableMouseFunction()
    set mouse=a
endfunction
```